# Why isn't the `assign` property deallocated under ARC? Pure luck?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

**UPDATE:** I thought the default behavior under ARC is `assign`, but it is `strong`. So, don't bother reading the question, it is useless :)

---

Consider the following code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface TestClass: NSObject
@property (atomic) NSMutableArray *strings; //"assign" by default
@end
@implementation TestClass
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    TestClass *testObject = [TestClass new];
    testObject.strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //(*) Why isn't strings array deallocated here under ARC? There are no strong references to it.
    [testObject.strings addObject:@"str1"];
    [testObject.strings addObject:@"str2"];
    [testObject.strings addObject:@"str3"];
    NSLog(@"Strings: %@", testObject.strings);
    return YES;
}
@end
```

Here `strings` property is declared as `assign` (by default). So, if I'm not mistaken, there are no strong references to this array in the code at all. So, from my point of view `strings` should be deallocated at `(*)`. However, the code works and prints the array.

Why? My possible explanation is that there are some implementation details related to the `NSMutableArray`, so there are some internal references left to the `strings` array, so it remains valid. So it is just pure luck. Am I right? I've tricked the system into returning `retainCount`, it was equal to `2` at the point of `NSLog`.

If I change the property declaration to `(atomic, weak)`, the array is `nil` as expected.

I use Xcode 7.1.1 (7B1005) with OS X 10.11.2 (15C30). I checked the DEBUG version in the iOS simulator.

I found a code like this on the internet, and expected it to crash, but it didn't. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under ARC the default ownership is `strong` not `assign`, see the [Clang ARC documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations) for details.

Comment: This is embarrassing. Thank you) And thanks for the documentation link.